# How to deal with FutureWarning regarding applying int to a Series with one item?

Tags: python, pandas

When running the following code

```py
import turtle
import pandas

FONT = 'monaco', 10, "bold"

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("U.S. States Game")
# screen.bgpic("blank_states_img.gif")
image = "blank_states_img.gif"
screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)

data = pandas.read_csv("50_states.csv")
all_states = data.state.to_list()
answer_state = screen.textinput(title="Guess the state name", prompt="Whats another state name?").title()
print(answer_state)
if answer_state in all_states:
    t = turtle.Turtle() 
    t.hideturtle() 
    t.penup() 
    state_data = data[data.state == answer_state] 
    t.goto(int(state_data.x), int(state_data.y)) 
    t.write(answer_state, font=FONT)
    screen.exitonclick()
```

this error keeps showing up:

> FutureWarning: Calling int on a single element Series is deprecated and will raise a `TypeError` in the future. Use `int(ser.iloc[0])` instead

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This is not an error, just a warning that something you does will be deprecated in future versions of the lib. Is ther more output which indicates where the warnung is emitted.

Comment: The warning is self-explanatory. In `int(state_data.x)`, `state_data.x` is a single-element pandas series, and in the future you will need to rewrite it as the warning states, `int(state_data.x.iloc[0])`

Answer (score 2):

for me worked like this:

```
t.goto(int(state_data.x.iloc[0]), int(state_data.y.iloc[0]))
```

Comment: This answer is in the "low quality answers queue" and **may** be voted for deletion. I suggest you try to expand the content detail to avoid that happening.

Answer (score 1):

That is a future warning, meaning there is not currently a problem with your code, but in a future update of pnadas the code you used will no longer be supported and will instead raise an error.

I think line 22 (`t.goto(int(state_data.x), int(state_data.y))`) is causing the warning.

There are two solutions to this, one better than the other:

1. Change your code to use a different method (`int(ser.iloc[0])` as the error suggested), this is the better method as it will work both now and in future versions. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) is the documentation on the code it suggests to use.
2. Make sure you only run the code on versions that support your implementation. While possible this is a bad option and should not be picked if possible.

Comment: Also, when posting in the future please include a short summary of the problem in the title.

Answer (score 1):

When running these two lines:

```
state_data = data[data.state == answer_state] 
t.goto(int(state_data.x), int(state_data.y))
```

The first line is saying "get me all elements of data where the state is equal to answer_state", but there could be any number of such elements; the operation returns a dataframe, and data_state.x returns a series, but if that series has more than one element you can't sensibly convert that into a single int. Python tries to, but that future warning appears to let you know that that feature may not be around for long. Change the second line above to this:

```
t.goto(int(state_data.x[0]), int(state_data.y[0]))
```

And it should work for you, though you might still run into some issues if there is no data where data.state == answer_state!

P.S. For future stack overflow post, make sure to include information about the error and platform within the post title

Answer (score 0):

rewrite this line:

```
t.goto(int(state_data.x), int(state_data.y))
```

as

```
t.goto(current_data.iloc[0, 1], current_data.iloc[0, 2])
```

You can learn more on pandas DataFrame iloc property here: [https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/ref_df_iloc.asp#:~:text=The%20iloc%20property%20gets%2C%20or%20sets%2C%20the%20value,another%20list%3A%20df.iloc%20%5B%20%5B0%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%201%5D%5D](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/ref_df_iloc.asp#:%7E:text=The%20iloc%20property%20gets%2C%20or%20sets%2C%20the%20value,another%20list%3A%20df.iloc%20%5B%20%5B0%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%201%5D%5D)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is the incorrect assumption that `state_data.x` and `state_data.y` return a [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) when they in fact return a pandas [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html).

In the warning it says

> Calling int on a single element Series is deprecated

You can confirm that `state_data.x` and `state_data.x` are Series objects by printing their type:

```
print(f'state_data.x type: {type(state_data.x)}\nstate_data.y type: {type(state_data.y)}')
```

One solution is using [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) on the Series, as is mentioned in the warning. A Series is a one-dimensional [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html). Therefor we need to specify the index in the ndarray when using iloc.

`state_data.x.iloc[0]`

If the underlying data looks like this:

```
state,x,y
Alabama,139,-77
Alaska,-204,-170
Arizona,-203,-40
Arkansas,57,-53
```

`state_data.x.iloc[0]` and `state_data.y.iloc[0]` will both return int values.

Another solution is using [item()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html#pandas.Series.item) on the Series. This will return the first element of the underlying data of the Series. Which in this case is an int.

```
x = state_data.x.item()
```

In other words there is no need to cast the values to an int in either solution. As the data will be returned as an int in both cases. Which resolves the warning you where getting.