# How to get IQRs to work after upgrade to Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iqr

The following code is meant to calculate the IQR of dataframes for follow on regression in ML data analysis.  The code worked at first, but then had to upgrade Anaconda to get libraries. Code is

#Checking different percentiles

```py
    pd.DataFrame(MyData['Age']).describe(percentiles=(1,0.99,0.9,0.75,0.5,0.3,0.1,0.01))
```

The code for IQR

Checking Outlier by definition and treating outliers

```py
   #Getting median age
    Age_col_df = pd.DataFrame(MyData['Age'])
    Age_median = Age_col_df.median()
```

```py
    #Getting IQR of Age column   
    Q3 = Age_col_df.quantile(q=0.75)
    Q1 = Age_col_df.quantile(q=0.25)
    IQR = Q3-Q1
```

```py
    #Deriving boundaries of Outliers
    IQR_LL = int(Q1 - 1.5*IQR)
    IQR_UL = int(Q3 + 1.5*IQR)
```

```py
    #Finding and treating outliers - both lower and upper end
    MyData.loc[MyData['Age']>IQR_UL , 'Age'] = int(Age_col_df.quantile(q=0.90))
    MyData.loc[MyData['Age']<IQR_LL , 'Age'] = int(Age_col_df.quantile(q=0.01))
```

The errors that I get are

```py
    C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19008\1214848077.py:13: FutureWarning: Calling int on a single element Series is deprecated and will raise a TypeError in the future. Use int(ser.iloc[0]) instead
    C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19008\1214848077.py:14: FutureWarning: Calling int on a single element Series is deprecated and will raise a TypeError in the future. Use int(ser.iloc[0]) instead
    C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19008\1214848077.py:17: FutureWarning: Calling int on a single element Series is deprecated and will raise a TypeError in the future. Use int(ser.iloc[0]) instead 
    C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19008\1214848077.py:18: FutureWarning: Calling int on a single element Series is deprecated and will raise a TypeError in the future. Use int(ser.iloc[0]) instead
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for the corrections to grammar/formatting.  Thank you kindly in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this an actual runtime error or just a warning? It says it will be an error in the future. It also tells you what the problem is: you are calling int() on pd.Series.

Change these lines:

Q3 = Age_col_df.quantile(q=0.75).iloc[0]
Q1 = Age_col_df.quantile(q=0.25).iloc[0]

MyData.loc[MyData['Age']>IQR_UL , 'Age'] = int(Age_col_df.quantile(q=0.90).iloc[0])
MyData.loc[MyData['Age']<IQR_LL , 'Age'] = int(Age_col_df.quantile(q=0.01).iloc[0])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with FutureWarning regarding applying int to a Series with one item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256618/how-to-deal-with-futurewarning-regarding-applying-int-to-a-series-with-one-item)